# Is there a good way of extracting data from GUI on Windows OS using python libraries?

Tags: c#, python, windows, user-interface, text-extraction

I'm currently working on a project which requires me to extract data from GUI on Windows OS - say I need to extract content such as the URL in my browser or the name of the attachment on Gmail.

I have already tried LDTP/Cobra, however it's pretty slow - each request can take up to 5 seconds and I need this library to be reasonably fast. Besides that, the LDTP/Cobra is pretty outdated and the latest MSI file doesn't work with python 3.* unless you modify the library itself.

I've been also researching the pywin API, however, it seems that you can't really extract anything with FindWindowEx and WM_GETTEXT method anymore, but I might be wrong.

My question is - is there any other library that would allow me to extract basically anything from a given Window? Maybe I'm missing an important part of the mentioned libraries? Ideally, I'm looking for a python library, but if there is no other way I could try and write some C# code.

Comment: Do you mean pywin32 under "pywin"? There are many open source tools: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/wiki/UI-Automation-tools-ratings For example, pywinauto is capable to use MS UI Automation API technology under the hood. See the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

Comment: For browser related automation Selenium is better, though pywinauto is capable to do that with some tricks like command line option `chrome.exe --force-renderer-accessibility`. But Selenium is really an industry standard for in-browser automation.